# How to make floated right div fixed without changing the current look of the page

Tags: html, css

I have a page that mainly contains two DIVs, acting as two columns, 
Left div hold the site content, and right div holds the Ads.

I want the right div to be in a fixed position without changing the look of the page.
for example, if add this css:

position: fixed;
right: 0;

and see how the page will look like!

I created a jsfiddle example, I hope you'll help me fix this issue:

[**Here is the jsfiddle link**](http://jsfiddle.net/pnsCc/1/)

Here is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">

<div class="right">
    This is a fixed div

</div> 
<div class="left">

    This is a normal div
    <p>
        Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
        </p>
The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
<p>        
        There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.
        </p>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.left {
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 50px;
    border: 2px dashed #f0f
}

.right {
    float: right;
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 2px dashed #00f;
    /* position: fixed;
    right: 0;  */   
}

.container {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: what's the definition of "ruining" for you?

Comment: Right div is on the right side only... what's the problem?

Comment: Some sort of sketch or description of the look your trying to achieve might help.

Comment: @webeno without runing===without changing the current look of the page, so to keep the same look

Comment: @kdureidy "same look" becomes abstract as soon as you start interacting with the page, but have a look at the answers below, you might find the best guess... ;)

Comment: @Dikesh the problem is that it's not in a fixed position, please read the question "I want the right div to be in a fixed position"

Comment: @Jahed i want the same look that you see in the jsfiddle example, the only change I want to make, is to make the right div FIXED

Comment: @kdureidy think it's time for you to choose a good answer... or do you not like any of them...?

Comment: @webeno all of the answers below will ruin the design once you resize the page, you will see that divs will go inside each other's

Comment: @kdureidy have you seen my answer? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23309611/how-to-make-floated-right-div-fixed-without-ruining-the-ui/23309683#23309683](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23309611/how-to-make-floated-right-div-fixed-without-ruining-the-ui/23309683#23309683) - does it ruin your design?

Comment: @webeno yep, and i accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting a height for `left` and set it to `overflow:auto`, this way only the content of left will scroll and everything else will remain as is:

```css
.left {
    overflow: auto;
    min-height: 50px;
    border: 2px dashed #f0f;
    height:300px /* set this to the height of your page, preferably */
}
```

I updated your fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/pnsCc/6/)**

Comment: I removed the height property, it's accebtable for me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution from your example is to fix the width of the left div. Then position the right div from the middle of the page + the additional amount taken by the left div (since the left div is larger than 50% of its centred parent).

So the left div's width is fixed at 332px. The container is 600px, so it's 332 - 600/2 + 10 margin + 2 left div border = an offset of 44px.

So we get (where `...` is the existing styles):

```
.left {
    ...
    width:332px;
}

.right {
    ...
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: 44px;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pnsCc/7/

Due to the way you've styled the example (with a fixed-width and centred container), it's as far as I know, impossible to position the right div properly when the window's width goes small enough and causes horizontal scrolling since `fixed` is based on the window size rather than the document's.

To fix that, you'll need to use CSS media queries to un-fix the right div when the window goes below a certain width.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

```
@media (max-width: 620px) {
    .right {
        position:static;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pnsCc/10/

If you are going to do that, you would ideally, relayout your entire page for that width to prevent horizontal scrolling.

Comment: I wonder how it will look in the mobile devices, because when you resize the page to be smaller, the divs will go inside each other

Comment: It's not that hard, try it yourself and learn from it. I've added the code anyway.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help, I wish I could accept two answers at a time. but still I was hope to find a solution that keep the left div without a fixed size, but it seems to be undoable

Answer (score 0):

It only takes a few minor modifications to your CSS:

```
.left {
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 50px;
    border: 2px dashed #f0f;
    margin-right: 270px;
}

.right {
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 50px;
    border: 2px dashed #00f;
    position: fixed;
    left: 456px;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8SZWX/

You might have to tune widths a bit, and be careful with extra width caused by padding and borders.

Answer (score 0):

change the css of .left class

```
.left {
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 50px;
    border: 2px dashed #f0f;
    max-width:350px;
    width : 350px;
}
```

and right class like this

```
.right {
    float: right;
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 2px dashed #00f;
     position: fixed;
    right: 0;    
}
```

updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbandi/pnsCc/3/)

Answer (score -1):

```css
.left {
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 50px;
    border: 2px dashed #f0f
}

.right {
    position:fixed;   /* here is your answer */
    float: right;
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 2px dashed #00f;
    /* position: fixed;
    right: 0;  */   
}

.container {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

Comment: did you even run that garbage?

Comment: well, the definition of "ruining" can be different for everyone, but your code definitely ruins it for me...